# How to adapt "Analyzing National Health Interview Survey code" without using SAScii Library or read.SAScii function

Tags: r

I am trying to adapt this code here as practice: https://github.com/DwieshaE/Analyzing_National_Health_Interview_Survey_Data/blob/master/NHANES%20Rscript%20V2%20without%202a.R

The computer I am using right now do not let me download SAScii library, so I am trying to adapt it to .do versions. Can you help me about the read.SAScii function here? I think I need to use load and import instead but I dont know what is the import version of the code, also the original file is zipped.

The original:

```
## Nhis data set
setwd("C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/NHANES")
library(rio); install_formats()
library(dplyr); library(survey)
### reading dat files form nhanes sascii package is required
library(SAScii) ###Load Packages


### Reading functional disability .dat files 2011 - 2014. The 2015 to 2017 were already in csv

##?SAScii; ?read.SAScii
## functional disability 2014
NHISlocation <- "ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/NHIS/2014/funcdisb.zip"
NHISread.in.instructions <- "ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Program_Code/NHIS/2014/funcdisb.sas"

X.df <- read.SAScii(NHISlocation, 
                NHISread.in.instructions, zipped = T)

export(X.df, "fdb2014.csv")

###Functional disability 2013
NHISlocation <- "ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/NHIS/2013/funcdisb.zip"
NHISread.in.instructions <- "ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Program_Code/NHIS/2013/funcdisb.sas"

X1.df <- read.SAScii(NHISlocation, 
                    NHISread.in.instructions, zipped = T)

export(X1.df, "fdb2013.csv")
```

What I have done so far:

```
> setwd("C:/Users/elif/Downloads")
> install.packages('rio', dependencies = TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
> install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
> NHISlocation <- "ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/NHIS/2014/funcdisb.zip"
> NHISread.in.instructions < ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Program_Code/NHIS/2014/funcdisb.do
library(rio); install_formats()
library(dplyr); 
library(survey)
```

I am new to coding, sorry for this and future basic questions! :)

Comment: Why can't you install the package?

Comment: I am using the computer in the library temporarily, they are not allowed to install something

Comment: Why not use the cloud version of R (free) instead? Can install whatever you like and use anywhere with internet.

Comment: Oh my god THANK YOU!!!!!!! I was not aware of this, thank you!!